# What species is this alien on the bridge of USS Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, aliens, character-identification, star-trek-discovery

Here is a screencap from *Star Trek: Discovery*, Episode 4 of the first Season:

[image]

What species is the big-headed *insectoid/arachnoid/reptilian/somethingoid* alien to the left of the screen, standing on the station directly behind the black girl? Here is a close-up of our new friend in all of his beauty (well, sort of):

[image]

Is he a new alien created appositely for *Discovery*, or was this species already seen before in the franchise? What do we know about him or his species, other that probably trying to wear his jersey is not his favourite thing to do in the morning?

Comment: An answer to this question will need to wait. I do not believe any source has specified either the species name or the personal name of the character.

Comment: I asked because his appearance is somewhat familiar to me, but I can't say if he reminds me an alien from Star Trek or from somewhere else

Comment: He/it looks a little like a Draman from the animated series. Do you have a shot of his/it's hands?

Comment: Upon finding a clearer picture, they aren't very similar.

Comment: where's the hand drawn red circles?

Comment: It resembles a [Hyach](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/File:Hyach.jpg) (from *Babylon 5*).  Maybe that's why it seems familiar to you.

Comment: @NKCampbell Is green all right? :) More seriously, with all the red parts in the background, another color is standing out more.

Comment: its the bugs from StarshipTrooper. The universes have merged and peace has been reached

Comment: I agree with @Naib. Reminds me of the Brain Bug from Starship Troopers. http://kaiju.wdfiles.com/local--files/wiki:brain_bug/brain_bug_1997_01.jpg

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It might be an "Osnullus", a name which is attached to some large head prosthetics in behind-the-scenes material, but I can't find a primary source connecting the alien we see with that name.

Here is a slightly clearer picture of the character.

[image]

Several sites have reported Alex Kurtzman describing the character during a set walkthrough. [Scott Collura](http://www.cetusnews.com/tech/Star-Trek--Discovery---Series-Premiere-Review.HJmHokQwo-.html) reported the following from a set visit.

> During our tour with the make-up prosthetics department (seen here with Lt. Saru's headpiece and Sarek's ears), we learned that at least two new types of beings will be part of the USS Discovery crew. One is known as Osnullus (he/she/it has a big old alien head) and the other is a synthetic human-like female character called Airiam who works on the bridge of the ship. The goal is to have aliens naturally mixed in with the human characters in the background as well as in the main cast.

Osnullus has been described as a new race for Discovery, and I am not aware of any similar-looking creature in previous shows or movies.

**Other Sources**

[TV Guide](http://www.tvguide.com/special/fall-preview/gallery/star-trek-discovery-behind-the-scenes/5/) mentions James Mackinnon showing off "Osnullus". However, the image used in that piece is of Saru's headpiece.

Comment: Funny, *os nullus* roughly translates from latin into *no mouth* .

Comment: Can you provide some links to better reference this?

Comment: http://trekcore.com/blog/2017/09/lots-of-new-star-trek-discovery-information-arrives-from-august-press-visit-to-toronto-sets/  - http://www.tvguide.com/special/fall-preview/gallery/star-trek-discovery-behind-the-scenes/5/  - best links I could find that at least indicate it's a real name. The make-up image sadly doesn't have enough detail to confirm. In fact, it looks more like the makeup in the two links displayed are actually Saru elements, not the alien in question

Comment: The cowl in that image is definitely Saru (check the ears), which is why I didn't link it. There was clearly discussion about another prop, but no images of that other headpiece.

Comment: Missed opportunity to not do a scene with Cronenburg

Comment: In the meantime, the species name Osnullus is canon, because it was seen as written text on screen: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Osnullus

Answer (score 1):

I think 'Osnullus' is the character name, could also be the species. But the actress, [Avaah Blackwell](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm4389000/), has it listed on her account under that name.